# Exchanging messages between UI Thread and Background Networking Thread

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an android app just for personal use. The app communicates with a server by TCP sockets. If the user makes an input it needs to be sent immediately. Also there can be messages from the server at any given time which need to be shown on the UI. For all the networking stuff I have a background thread in mind.

Since I need to pass messages From the UI to the networking thread at any user input and also messages from the networking thread to the UI at any given time my question follows: How can I pass the messages? I already read about the Handler class for 3hours and I couldn't figure out anything. How do handlers work? What would be a neat and smooth running implementation of that? I look more for a strategy to accomplish this goal, not necessarily implementation details.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: See Looper class description (API). There is simple thread with handler  example.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html Use this I too had a lot of problems with handlers but the async task handles all that annoying work for you. Make sure you use onPrexecute() and onPostExecute() to update the UI. Hope this helps.

Comment: AsyncTask will be for one time execution. You'd have to continuously create / destroy network connections.

Comment: True true. I'm curious then how would you approach the problem? Service? Threads and Handlers?

Comment: I posted a new answer.  Threads are a must either way. Handler, as in the answer, work when the activity and network lifespan are tied together.  If you need to continually access the network, but the activity may be closed (e.g. music streaming), then a service is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AsyncTask` in this case.
You can call it on the UI thread and in onPostExecute do what you want to do with the messages. 
It is a much cleaner approach than doing all the dirty networking work there.

Comment: @JakeWilson801 Isn't AsyncTask for one-time-executions of something large? Because the app should be able to receive messages at any time, which I cannot foresee, I would have to restart the AsyncTask as soon as it shut down to display the changes properly and not only on user inputs. Isnt a Handler better suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll say I'm learning this myself, but I've managed to get this exact setup working in a prototype.  If anyone sees something that should be changed to work better in Android, by all means let me know.

Second, I'm using empty messages so that we have code that would actually work. I assume that creating message objects is straight forward enough.

## **Part 1 - UI to Network Thread**

As far as I have seen, Handler is the answer you need, but it's not the whole picture.  Deucalion's comment about Looper is where you need to look next.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
  public Handler mHandler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
}
```

This setup is counter intuitive at first, you need to create the Handler object between the `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` calls, inside your `run()` method.  I don't know the magic behind the scenes, haven't had a chance to get that far down the rabbit hole.

**Important Note**:
The sample shows an anonymous Handler() being created. I highly recommend subclassing Handler in your own class and then using an instance of that.  It's just a matter of reusability, a lot of network code ends up being the same.

So, rename `LooperThread` to `NetworkThread`, or whatever you'd like it to be, and put your connection code in the `run()` method, but outside the `Looper.prepare() / Looper.loop()` block (again I don't know how the magic works, so I'm just assuming this is better to do than to have it inside).

```
// process incoming messages here
```

Tends to look like this:

```
switch(msg.what)
{
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break
}
```

The LooperThread example has `public Handler mHandler;` but I prefer to make the handler private and create a method to return it. I do this just to prevent the handler from being accessible until after the network connection is established. No connection, nothing to do with the messages.

So, somewhere in your activity code you create the `NetworkThread` object, run it, and then get the Handler from it.

```
NetworkThread network = new NetworkThread();
new Thread(network).run();
//Handler networkHandler = network.handler;
Handler networkHandler = network.getHandler();
```

Then you just send messages to that handler as needed.

```
networkHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

---

## Part 2 - Network Thread to UI

There are a couple of different ways to handle this. You can create a handler inside the Activity class. All activities have a Looper already setup, so calling Looper.prepare and Looper.loop seem to cause problems.

In my code I create a handler in the `onCreate()` method, and then I pass it into my `NetworkThread` object.  There may be better places to create this Handler, I don't know what will happen if your application is suspended and then started again later with `onResume()` or `onRestart()`

```
public NetworkThread(Handler mainHandler)
{
    this.mainHandler = mainHandler;
}
```

Then anywhere else I need to send a message to the UI:

```
this.mainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

I prefer this method because the Handler code, that does the actual work, either exists in the classes the actually respond to the message (using the anonymous Handler objects) or in Handler subclasses that may be in the same package.

You could also pass in the `Activity` or a `View` to the network thread and from that call `runOnUIThread(Runnable)`, but that requires you pass in a Runnable. So the code that is meant to work on the UI is being written or referenced in the Networking classes.

---

### Update

You could also use a Service for this. The method above works when the Activity and the Networking have the same life span. If we only need network connection while the Activity is active.

If you need network connectivity beyond the life of the Activity, in a music streaming app for example, then going with a Service would be a better choice.  It didn't seem like this was specifically what you were looking for the question.